# Is "Suppose you did ..." guessing that 'you' already did?

Tags: expressions, colloquial-language

> **571 suppose, supposing and what if**
>   (...) A past tense makes the suggestion sound less definite.
>
> > *Daddy, can I watch TV? ~ **Suppose** you **did** your homework first*.
>
> M. Swan, Practical English Usage, §571

I wonder what the daddy's reply means.
a) "I guess you've already finished your homework",
b) "I think you'll finish your homework first (if so,/so/then you can)",
c) "If you finish your homework first"
d) It's vague, and is more or less meaning all of the above.

Is it a kind of words that is typical from a parent to the kid?
Is there an omitted subject 'I' before the 'suppose'?

Comment: It's (c) ***If** you finish your homework first (before I consider and answer your question), **THEN** by implication you're more likely to get the answer you want*. The first word should be understood as a cut-down version of ***Let us** suppose that...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that, of your options, (c) is the closest.

I might paraphrase it like this:

> "I suggest you finish your homework first."

(Usage note: When a parent uses *suggest* in a context like this one, it pretty much means the same thing as, "Not unless you finish your homework first," only stated in a gentler, milder tone.)

As for the omitted "I", it's almost more like a rhetorical question:

> "How about if you finish your homework first?"

Comment: Or even ***Say** you finish[ed] your homework first.* There are various alternatives all implying something like ***Alternatively***, but the choice may affect what tense works next.